# Why can I not use echo with GIT_ASKPASS

Tags: git, sh

I am trying to provide a password to git through GIT_ASKPASS like this:

```
export PASSWORD=<secret>
export GIT_ASKPASS="/usr/bin/echo $PASSWORD"
git clone https://username@domain.com/git-repo/repo.git
```

But I get:

```
 error: cannot run /usr/bin/echo <secret>: No such file or directory
```

So it seems I am not allowed to give parameters in `GIT_ASKPASS`?

Now I could create a script which just contains:

```
/usr/bin/echo $PASSWORD
```

But I am wondering: Is there a way of doing this without creating a temporary script?

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that the whole variable is interpreted as a program name. So what about making another script, let’s call it `password_provider.sh`, which would tell us the password?

```
#! /bin/sh
echo <secret>
```

Then you can run: `export GIT_ASKPASS="./password_provider.sh"`

### Security notice

Keep in mind that this means storing password in plain text which is generally not a good security practice. You should prefer public key authentication or true [credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/711006) whenever possible.

Comment: You could drop the `export` line, and just `echo $PASSWORD`, since the idea here is to inherit the password from the environment. But this is using a script (not necessarily a *temporary* script) so it may be counter to the spirit of the question. :-) It also remains quite insecure, as it is possible to view environment variables of other processes. What is needed in the end is a *credential helper*, and the OP should read up on these.

Comment: @torek Yes, it _is_ insecure but OP explicitly asked for plain `echo`… I’ve added a link for how to use a credential helper.

Comment: Yes, I'm just emphasizing that even if you *don't* put the plain-text password into the provider script, it remains insecure (as you pointed out originally!).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for echo in the wrong location. Try running `whereis echo` and substitute that, on a mac echo is located at `/bin/echo`.

Comment: Yep, same on Ubuntu. However, `/usr/bin/echo` works for Git Bash on Windows. This would still make the script unportable.

Comment: Good catch! But I am on fedora, and here it is: /usr/bin/echo

Comment: @Nathan You’ll better go with `$(which echo)` to be portable.

Answer (score 2):

## The Problem

As others have said, you can't pass arguments within the string. The whole string is interpreted as the command.

```sh
# this works
echo foo
```

```sh
# this does not
"echo foo"
```

## Working Solution(s)

I went through every possible iteration of how to do this:

- SSH Public Keys

  - SSH_ASKPASS
- API Access Tokens

  - **GIT_ASKPASS**
  - .gitconfig insteadOf
  - .gitconfig [credential]
  - .git-credentials
  - .netrc

And I compiled a list of EVERY. SINGLE. METHOD. that actually worked.

I actually recommend the **.gitconfig insteadOf** approach, but for GIT_ASKPASS, this is what I did:

### From [Git Credentials & Private Packages Cheatsheet](https://coolaj86.com/articles/vanilla-devops-git-credentials-cheatsheet/)

How to create an `GIT_ASKPASS` script:

```sh
echo 'echo $MY_GIT_TOKEN' > $HOME/.git-askpass
```

How to use it:

```sh
export MY_GIT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
export GIT_ASKPASS=$HOME/.git-askpass
git clone https://token@code.example.com/project.git
```

The script receives stdin in the form of:

```
Password for 'scheme://host.tld':
```

The script receives Git ENVs such as:

```sh
GIT_DIR=/Users/me/project/.git
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.19.0_1/libexec/git-core
GIT_PREFIX=
```

More details in the [cheatsheet](https://coolaj86.com/articles/vanilla-devops-git-credentials-cheatsheet/).